# Printing variable Live Template for Javascript in IDEA

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

In Java code I use a live template `soutv`. 
So if I type `myVar` there it automatically duplicates it and the result is

```
System.out.println("myVar = " + myVar);
```

Can I create the same custom live template for Javascript code ? So the desirable result should be

```
console.log('myVar = ', myVar);
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Settings | Editor | Live Templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a live template for `console.log()` in **Preferences | Editor | Live Templates**:

[image]

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.1/using-live-templates.html, https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm